# Are those two identically looking C++ function templates functionally equivalent?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Let's say we have a program that defines several function templates:

```
template<typename T>
void g(T) {}

struct A {};

//this template only sees the definition of g above
//the usage of g does not depend on the parameter of the template
template<typename T = void>
decltype(T(), (g)(A{})) f(A a)
{
   return (g)(a);
}

A g (A a)
{
  return a;
}
//this template sees both overloads of g
//and still the usage of g does not depend on the parameter of the template
template<typename T = void>
decltype(T(), (g)(A{})) f(A a)
{
  return (g)(a);
}
```

This program contains two copies of the code that defines function template *f*. In general, creating equivalent overloads is forbidden by C++ standard.
The question is whether those two templates are equivalent according to the standard?

Had those two templates used *g* as dependent name they would be considered eqivalent, as the standard explicitly says so:

> For determining whether two dependent names ([temp.dep]) are equivalent, only the name itself is considered, not the result of name lookup in the context of the template. If multiple declarations of the same function template differ in the result of this name lookup, the result for the first declaration is used.

But here the usage of *g* does not depend on T (while being a part of an expression that depends on T).

Compilers disagree on whether those two definitions should be allowed: clang accepts it, GCC and Visual C++ does not (See https://godbolt.org/g/LUW1iM).

Comment: you want to overload based on the return type?

Comment: @tobi303 Templates can be overloaded based on return type, but it's just a made-up example.

Comment: i missed the language lawyer tag ans wondering what that would be good for ;)

Comment: Did you intend to permit a T that overloads , possibly changing the answer?

Comment: @Yakk, I do not. Let's say I have decltype((void)T(), (g)(A{})).

Comment: @AndyG So, you think _g_ should be considered a dependent name. Why?

Comment: Why is it that you have tagged the question c++11, but your godbolt link uses c++17? And what standard version is the blockquote from?

Comment: The question was asked 5 years ago. There's no way I'd remember, I don't think it used c++17 by default back then. The question applies to C++11, though if there are differences in later standards it would be good to mention them.